# Struct in header file, allocation in stack vs in heap?

Tags: c

I'm learning C myself and stumble upon a "strange" behavior. I'm trying to replicate the list data structure of Python, using C.

For the header file `listint.h`, I have this:

```
#include "stdint.h"

#ifndef LISTINT_H
#define LISTINT_H

typedef struct { // simple list of int
    int ** list; // void pointer to the array of pointer
    uint32_t length; // size of the list
} ListInt;

void ListInt_print(ListInt * self);
void ListInt_append(ListInt * self, int * item); // add pointer of an item - pointer to the list

#endif
```

For the `listint.c` (compiled to `liblistint.so`), there is implementation of the `ListInt_append`:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "listint.h"

void ListInt_append(ListInt * self, int * item) {
    if (self->list == NULL) { // uninitialized list
        int ** ptr;
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(int *));
        self->list = ptr;
        ptr[0] = item;
        self->length = 1;
        return;
    } else if (item != NULL) {
        int ** list_tmp; // temp list for realloc
        uint32_t new_size = self->length + 1;
        int ** ptr;
        if ((list_tmp = realloc(self->list, sizeof(int *) * new_size)) == NULL) {
            return;
        };
        self->list = list_tmp;
        list_tmp[new_size - 1] = item;
        self->length = new_size;
        return;
    };
    return;
};
```

For the test file, I have tried two versions:

The first one, I declare two variables of type ListInt list this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "listint.h"

void main() {
    ListInt mlist1;
    ListInt mlist2;

    printf("mlist1.list address %p\n", mlist1.list);
    printf("mlist2.list address %p\n", mlist2.list);
    printf("mlist1.length value %d\n", mlist1.length);
    printf("mlist2.length value %d\n", mlist2.length);

}
```

Output:

```
mlist1.list address (nil)
mlist2.list address 0x7ffc3c4d3e20
mlist1.length value -1701232544
mlist2.length value 0
```

Moreover, if I added this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
ListInt_append(&mlist1, &a);
ListInt_append(&mlist2, &b);
```

The `ListInt_append(&mlist2, &b);` will return `realloc() invalid pointer`

The second one, declaring the two pointers:

```
ListInt * mlist1 = malloc(sizeof(ListInt));
ListInt * mlist2 = malloc(sizeof(ListInt));
```

The initial values of attributes:

```
mlist1.list address (nil)
mlist2.list address (nil)
mlist1.length value 0
mlist2.length value 0
```

Running the following worked as expected:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
ListInt_append(&mlist1, &a);
ListInt_append(&mlist2, &b);
```

It seems I'm missing st very fundamental here. Plz pardon my lack of understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show complete code as a [mre]. For example, in the "first one" are those variables global or inside a function? It makes a difference. If it is inside a function and for `malloc` the allocated memory is not initialised. So printing the values immediately after the declaration/malloc is reading indeterminate values which can be anything.

Comment: From the Q title, you don't have a `struct` allocation in the header file. What you show is a type definition. If the allocation is with `malloc` it will be on the heap.

Comment: The `ListInt *mlist1 = malloc(sizeof(ListInt *));` is incorrect. It should be either `sizeof(ListInt)` or `sizeof(*mlist1)`.

Comment: If `mlist1` is an uninitialized local variable, printing its contents leads to undefined behaviour.  Any result is legitimate.

Comment: `mlist1.length value -1701232544` shows that not only did you probably not initialise the `length` property, you are also using the wrong format specifier. You should use `%u` there instead of the `%d` that you're probably using.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right I updated to `malloc(sizeof(ListInt))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects defined with `ListInt mlist1;` and `ListInt mlist2;` inside functions are not given initial values. Their initial values are *indeterminate*, and the program behavior is generally not defined by the C standard when you attempt to use the values. (If the address of the object is taken, the program behavior becomes somewhat defined, but the value remains indeterminate.)

You can give them initial values with:

```
ListInt mlist1 = { 0, 0 }; // Initialize members in order.
ListInt mlist1 = { .list = 0, .length = 0; } // Initialize by member name.
```

Similarly, with `malloc`, no initial value is given. After allocation, you can give the structures values by assigning to their members, as with:

```
mlist1->list   = 0;
mlist1->length = 0;
```

Alternately, you can have the memory set to all zeros by using `ListInt *mlist1 = calloc(1, sizeof *mlist1);` instead of using `malloc`. That usually suffices, although technically it is not specified that all-zero bytes represents a null pointer, so the assignment method is more portable in theory.

If the objects were declared outside of a function or with `static`, as in `static ListInt mlist1;`, they would have static storage duration and would automatically be initialized with initial values of zero (including setting pointers to a null pointer value).

Comment: Thx I'll test giving them initial value. This is could be my bad behavior carried from coding with Python (giving attribute of an object value of `None` in `def __init__()`). One small question: why one of the address of `.list` of `mlist1` and `mlist2` was given value `0x7ffc3c4d3e20` when declaring as `ListInt mlist1`, clearly different from using `malloc` when both are `NULL`, which is a behavior that I expected?

Comment: Ok I got your answer, thx for giving the hint, good day sir.